# which is the best way of linking two forms by use of a Jbutton

Tags: netbeans6.5

I am having a `JFrame Form` as my main page with some `JButtons`. I want, if i click a `JButton`, another `JFrame Form` will appear and also find a way to navigate back to my main page from the opened `Jframe Form`. What is the best way to achieve this?

My project is `Java`>`Java Application`

Answer (score 1):

You can store the jform references somewhere and call their methods as you like.